# Socket.io in Express JS on connection execute multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I refer [this repo](https://github.com/onedesign/express-socketio-tutorial) to integrate socket.io.

What I want to achieve is, a countdown timer, which send to client every second, `setInterval` is run on server side. The result I get is

[image: Socket.io & Express JS]

The terminal there is `on.('connection')`, first time I refresh the page, it executed 4 times `on.('connection')`, the countdown is working fine. Then I refresh 2nd time, it executed 8 times `on.('connection')`, and the countdown timer also have 2 values there. Then continue.... 12 times, 16 times...

In **app.js**

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  res.io = io; 
  io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log(socket.id + ' connected.');
  }); 
  next();
});
```

In **routes/users.js**

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  models.User.findAll({
    include: [ {model: models.Task, as: 'tasks'} ]
  }).then(function(users) {

    var eventTime= new Date('2017-03-31 13:00:00').getTime();
    var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    var diffTime = eventTime - currentTime;
    var duration = moment.duration(diffTime*1000, 'milliseconds');
    var interval = 1000;

    setInterval(function() {
      duration = moment.duration(duration - interval, 'milliseconds');
      res.io.emit('countdown', { time_left: duration.hours() + ":" + duration.minutes() + ":" + duration.seconds() }); 
    }, interval);

    res.render('users', {
      title: 'Sequelize: Express Example',
      users: users
    });   
  });   
});
```

Anything goes wrong here?

Comment: please explain your question ?

Comment: I want to create a countdown timer, usually countdown is done by js in front end. but I want to do it in backend, thus i use socket.io. when I debug the on connection in server side _(i put `console.log`)_ to show the debug message. it shows 4 times the same message, when I refresh my browser, it shows 8 times, followed by 12, 16 times, etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/2173#issuecomment-119829826)

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.removeAllListeners(); <---------- ADD THIS LINE
  console.log(socket.id + ' connected.');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you probably your keeping `io.on('connection')` event within setInterval. That's why it every time keeps on replication in *2.

You can do it like this if you want to achieve countdown timer :

```
io.on('connection', function (socket){
  var tick = 0;
  setInterval(function(){

    socket.emit('timer', tick++)
  }, 1000);
})
```

Now you can listen to `timer` event on front-end and display result.
Thanks

Comment: Sorry if my question not clear. Now I add more code to my question. Thanks